# storing sqlite database in icloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

is it possible to store SQlite into iCloud after exiting application and pulling when we open application ?but tutorials are telling to use core data only, is not possible to do it
through Sqlite only?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you shouldn't use SQLite and iCloud, the tutorials are right. From the [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html),

> Using iCloud with a SQLite database is possible only if your app uses Core Data to manage that database. Accessing live database files in iCloud using the SQLite interfaces is not supported and will likely corrupt your database.

However I'm not entirely sure you want to do what you think you want to do. Remember that if the user has enabled device backup to iCloud, your application's documents directory will be backed up. It really only makes sense to enable iCloud in your application if you're planning to use it as a synchronization tool between instances of your application (for instance between the user’s iPhone and iPad) or between platforms (and iOS and an OS X version of the application).

Comment: Can't i store Sqlite file into Document directoty and took backup into iCloud and whenever i need , cant i take(locally) and update and store again into
icoud?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If it's stored "locally" in the Documents directory and the user is backing up to iCloud, then it's already backed up to iCloud. There isn't any need for your application to store it separately in the cloud. The only reason to use iCloud is if you want to share the information between separate instances of your application running on difference devices (or with the arrival of Mountain Lion on different platforms). If you're not doing that, there isn't any need for iCloud at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not started with sqlite database operation then it is better you can go with core data.If you deadly want to have sqlite and at this point if you are not able to switch to the coredata then Please have look at my answer at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408695/how-to-use-icloud-for-syncing-my-sqlite-database-and-images-that-resides-in-the). Hope It will be helpful to you.