# How to use iCloud for syncing my sqlite database and images that resides in the folder in the library folder of application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, ios5, icloud

My requirement is , The app I am working on is having a folder name called "Private docmunets " created in the Library folder that reside in the application folder.There are images and a sqlite file which records users entries and images in this folder.

I have to make my app iCloud enabled, so I have to sync my sqlite database and all the images stored in Private docmunets folder on iCloud.

From the last two weeks I am searching for this but I did not get the right direction how to proceed.
Please any one suggest me which approach should I follow to fulfill my requirement.

Any link or sample code provided will be highly appreciated.

Please please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see my answer at these link. I had exact same requirement as yours.
1) [Syncing sqlite database with iCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953345/syncing-sqlite-database-with-icloud)
2) [How can I use iCloud to synchronize a .zip file between my apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047217/how-can-i-use-icloud-to-synchronize-a-zip-file-between-my-apps/10069242#comment13538082_10069242)

Comment: Hey do run sync code in background otherwise apple will reject app.Don't give button to sync with icloud. like u can do is call method after any updates/insert occur at ur db.

Comment: I have implemented syncing but data is not updating properly.